# Cannot use COM ports under my Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port

I am trying to obtain the COM port for a device but after I connect it, it is suddenly disconnected. I got the minicom package installed, and when I execute `dmesg | grep tty` I obatin this output:

```
[  268.880913] usb 2-1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  269.996530] usb 2-1.2: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ftdi_sio while 'brltty' sets config #1
[  269.997321] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
```

The device is recognized only for a few seconds. Is this a permissions problem? How can I get the COM port of my device?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I solved it myself. There is a package called brltty (Braille terminal driver) installed by default in Debian. I removed it and voila!, my device has COM port :D